# Building a dictionary out of components in a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file, where in each line, it contains a readname; a '+' or '-'; a position marked by a number.

I went ahead to first open the  file and have in Python script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys

    file=open('filepath')

    dictionary={}

    for line in file:

        reads=line.split()

        read_name=reads[0]

        methylation_state=reads[1] #this is a plus or minus

        position=int(reads[2])
```

I am having a hard time building a dictionary, where I would have {keys:values} as {methylation_state:position}.

If someone can please help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I hope this was clear enough.

**SAMPLES**

input1.txt

```
SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399861
SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399728
SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399735
SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399752
SRR1035452.21044_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5464:6620_length=36 + 31107092
```

input2.txt

```
SRR1035454.47_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:2618:2094_length=36 + 18922145
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36 + 51460469
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36 + 51460488
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36 + 51460631
```

Comment: What do you need exactly? The second and the third element of every line to be a part of a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I tried to make them into two lists and build it as key and value in dictionary through dict(zip(list1, list2)), but that wouldnt work

Comment: can you provide an expected result? because as i understood your question you will have at most two keys: '+' and '-' - is that what you want?

Comment: The expected result will be {second element in line: third element of each line}. For example, {'+' : '2324' , '-' : '3435',  '+' : '34345'}

Comment: so your dictionary will look as follows: {'+': int(position1), '-': int(position2)} independently of how many lines there are in your file???

Comment: it's not possible due to nature of dictionaries - all keys must be unique

Comment: Please put a sample input and a sample output in the question itself. Your description is vague.

Comment: I see. Please let me explain what I am trying to do. I have two files that I need to compare. Each line within a file has a read_name, followed by a plus or minus, followed by a number (position). I need to find all positions that are in one file, but not in another.

Comment: though, you may have something like: {'read_name1': {'+': 2324}, 'read_name2': {'-': 3435}, ... } or list of dictionaries: [{}, {}, {}]

Comment: for line in file:
    reads=line.split()
    qname1=reads[0]
    methylation_state1=reads[1] #this is either '+' or '-'
    position1=int(reads[2])

Comment: Which is also the same case for file2. I need to find a way to find position# that is in file 1, but not in file 2. and vice versa

Comment: @user5927494, and you don't care of 'read_name' and 'methylation_state', right? you just want to compare positions in two files - correct?

Comment: @MaxU No, the read_name is not important. However, I would like to find all Methylation_states with + and out of those with +s, the ones that are not overlapping positions.

Comment: you definitely should provide an example of two input files (two - three lines per file) and an example of expected output, because it's not clear what do you want to achieve...

Comment: file 1: SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399861 
SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399728 
SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399735 
SRR1035452.21010_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:4566:6721_length=36 + 59399752 
SRR1035452.21044_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5464:6620_length=36 + 31107092

Comment: file 2: SRR1035454.47_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:2618:2094_length=36 + 18922145 
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36 + 51460469
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36 + 51460488 
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36 + 51460631

Comment: I am looking for the positions (third element) for all lines that have + (second element) in positions that do NOT overlap. So position that is present in file one, but not in file two...and both have +

Comment: @MaxU I certainly hope that clears things up

Comment: 1. i didn't see any '-'. 2. what means X at the end of the 2nd line in file2?

Comment: @MaxU Some reads have a minus ('-') instead of a plus. I am sorry I just provided a couple of example lines

Comment: @MaxU I deleted that X. It is something I am not interested in. Just like the read_name. It contains no significance

Comment: can you use pandas module?

Comment: Definitely. Let me look into that now. Just not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code, that uses [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('a1.txt', names=['read_name','meth_state','position'], usecols=['position', 'meth_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
df1 = df1[(df1.meth_state == '+')]
print('DF1 %s' % ('-' * 50))
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_csv('a2.txt', names=['read_name','meth_state','position'], usecols=['position', 'meth_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
df2 = df2[(df2.meth_state == '+')]
print('DF2 %s' % ('-' * 50))
print(df2)

m1 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left', on='position')
print('DF2 - DF1 %s' % ('-' * 50))
print(df2[m1['meth_state_y'].isnull()])

m2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='position')
print('DF1 - DF2 %s' % ('-' * 50))
print(df1[m2['meth_state_y'].isnull()])
```

Output:

```
DF1 --------------------------------------------------
  meth_state  position
0          +  59399861
1          +  59399728
2          +  59399735
3          +  59399752
4          +  31107092
DF2 --------------------------------------------------
  meth_state  position
0          +  18922145
1          +  51460469
2          +  51460488
3          +  51460631
4          +  31107092
DF2 - DF1 --------------------------------------------------
  meth_state  position
0          +  18922145
1          +  51460469
2          +  51460488
3          +  51460631
DF1 - DF2 --------------------------------------------------
  meth_state  position
0          +  59399861
1          +  59399728
2          +  59399735
3          +  59399752
```

I would strongly recommend you to learn pandas - it might simplify your future work dramatically.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, because it simplified my work so much with Pandas. My goal is to learn it now instead of making a bunch of if statements that were complicating things even more. Thank you SO much again, Max!

Comment: Max, When I input my two text files that have about 80,000 reads in each and try to run the code, I keep on getting an error for merging dataframes (DF2-DF1, DF2-DF1). Ther ERROR that I getting is this: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:1825: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  "DataFrame index.", UserWarning)                                           Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Please note it makes the DF1 andDF2 without any problems. I tried changing the parameters for pandas.merge with no luck.

Comment: @user5927494, could you please open a new question and post there a few rows (5-10) from **both** DF1 and DF2, so that we could try to merge exactly the same (in terms of structures) dataframes? You can simply print a few elements from each dataframe...

Comment: Yes, of course! I tried to be as detailed as possible and put both input sample files and output dataframes built. thanks so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415892/pandas-merging-dataframes-module

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need simple sets of positions. Once you know all of the positions in each file you can perform many types of operations.

```
def positions(filename):
    # split on + and the second element is what we want
    return set(line.split('+')[1].strip() for line in open(filename)
        if '+' in line)

# get sets from both files
f1 = positions('f1.txt')
f2 = positions('f2.txt')
# with sets, subtraction shows you what is in one not the other
print("in 1 not 2", f1 - f2)
print("in 2 not 1", f2 - f1)
```

`positions` was implemented with python's compact "list comprehensions". I have no idea where that name came from. You could break it into parts to see the individual steps with the following, but the first implementation is clear once you get used to python.

```
def positions(filename):
     # open the file for reading
    with open(filename) as fp:
        # set will hold positions
        pos = set()
        # read the file line by line
        for line in fp:
            # we only care about lines with pluses
            if '+' in line:
                # split into two parts
                parts = line.split()
                # position is the second part but we need to get rid of 
                # extra spaces and newline
                position = parts[1].strip()
                # add to set. if position is already in set, you don't get
                # a second one, this one is dropped
                pos.add(position)
    return pos
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please write it in more detail...possibly breaking the code down so that Id know what I am doing with it? thanks again.