# Pandas Merging DataFrames Module

Tags: python, pandas, module, dataframe

I am somewhat new to Python and trying to use the Pandas module. Below are my sample files (first element of each line is the read_name; second element is the methylation_state; and third is the position).

My goal is to **first** extract all lines with '+' in input_sample1.txt and input_sample2.txt ***which I was able to do***

**Second** merge two data frames to extract positions that are in the first DF and not the second one; and then extract positions that are in the second DF and not in the second one.

This is what I have thus far and get errors for both m1 and m2 DFs with the following error:

*UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.   "DataFrame index.", UserWarning)*

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   from __future__ import print_function
   import pandas as pd
   import sys
   import pandas as pd


   df1=pd.read_csv('Input_Sample1.txt', names=['read_name', 'methylation_state', 'position'], usecols=['position', 'methylation_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
   df1 = df1[(df1.methylation_state == '+')]
   # print('df1 %s' % ('-' * 50))
   # print(df1)

   df2=pd.read_csv('Input_Sample2.txt', names=['read_name','methylation_state','position'], usecols=['position', 'methylation_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
   df2 = df2[(df2.methylation_state == '+')]
   #print('df2 %s' % ('-' * 50))
   #print(df2)
 #get an error for the following merged dataframes m1 and m2:
  m1=pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='position')
  print('df2 - df1 %s' % ('-' * 50))
  print(df2[m1['methylation_state_y'].isnull()])

  m2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='position')
  print('df1 - df2 %s' % ('-' * 50))
  print(df1[m2['methylation_state_y'].isnull()])
```

Input_Sample1.txt:

```
    SRR1035452.114_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3884:2095_length=36    +   37151024
SRR1035452.114_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3884:2095_length=36    +   37151031
SRR1035452.114_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3884:2095_length=36    +   37151189
SRR1035452.117_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3789:2132_length=36    +   23189251
SRR1035452.117_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3789:2132_length=36    +   23189248
SRR1035452.117_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3789:2132_length=36    +   23189242
SRR1035452.117_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3789:2132_length=36    +   23189086
SRR1035452.117_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:3789:2132_length=36    +   23189101
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644021
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644026
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644032
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644038
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644042
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644050
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644055
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644267
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644253
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644246
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644240
SRR1035452.211_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:5833:2115_length=36    +   60644236
SRR1035452.336_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:8029:2240_length=36    +   26775201
SRR1035452.336_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:8029:2240_length=36    +   26775193
SRR1035452.336_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:8029:2240_length=36    +   26775178
SRR1035452.336_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:8029:2240_length=36    +   26775012
SRR1035452.377_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:9240:2160_length=36    +   27851064
SRR1035452.377_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:9240:2160_length=36    +   27851253
```

INPUT_SAMPLE2.txt file:

```
   SRR1035454.47_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:2618:2094_length=36  -   18921902
SRR1035454.47_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:2618:2094_length=36 +   18921911
SRR1035454.47_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:2618:2094_length=36 +   18921919
SRR1035454.47_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:2618:2094_length=36 +   18921926
SRR1035454.47_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:2618:2094_length=36 +   18922145
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36    +   51460469
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36    +   51460488
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36    +   51460631
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36    +   51460613
SRR1035454.174_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:6245:2159_length=36    +   51460608
SRR1035454.215_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:7106:2100_length=36    -   30309836
SRR1035454.216_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:7129:2116_length=36    +   31856610
SRR1035454.216_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:7129:2116_length=36    +   31856602
SRR1035454.216_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:7129:2116_length=36    +   31856255
SRR1035454.270_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:8134:2171_length=36    +   26078372
SRR1035454.270_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:8134:2171_length=36    +   26078363
SRR1035454.306_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:9223:2098_length=36    +   55329938
SRR1035454.348_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:10157:2107_length=36   +   40179303
SRR1035454.348_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:10157:2107_length=36   +   40179299
SRR1035454.348_CRIRUN_726:7:1101:10157:2107_length=36   +   40179018
```

part of DF1 input:

```
0                     +  37151024
1                     +  37151031
2                     +  37151189
3                     +  23189251
4                     +  23189248
5                     +  23189242
6                     +  23189086
7                     +  23189101
8                     +  60644021
9                     +  60644026
10                    +  60644032
11                    +  60644038
12                    +  60644042
13                    +  60644050
14                    +  60644055
15                    +  60644267
16                    +  60644253
17                    +  60644246
18                    +  60644240
```

part of DF2 output:

```
      methylation_state  position
1                     +  18921911
2                     +  18921919
3                     +  18921926
4                     +  18922145
5                     +  51460469
6                     +  51460488
7                     +  51460631
8                     +  51460613
9                     +  51460608
11                    +  31856610
12                    +  31856602
13                    +  31856255
14                    +  26078372
```

***PLEASE NOTE*** Each text file contains about 80k lines. Any help/advice is much appreciated!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import pandas as pd

sys.stdout=open('CHG_comparison.txt', 'w')


ESfemale=pd.read_csv('Input_Sample1.txt', names=['read_name', 'methylation_state', 'position'], usecols=['position', 'methylation_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
ESfemale = ESfemale[(ESfemale.methylation_state == '+')]
# print('ESfemale CHF context of all methylation sites %s' % ('-' * 50))
# print(ESfemale)

EpiSC=pd.read_csv('Input_Sample2.txt', names=['read_name','methylation_state','position'], usecols=['position', 'methylation_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
EpiSC = EpiSC[(EpiSC.methylation_state == '+')]
#print('EpiSC CHG context of all methylation sites %s' % ('-' * 50))
#print(EpiSC)
#print(ESfemale[['methylation_state', 'position']].isin(EpiSC.to_dict(orient='list')))
diff1 = ESfemale.ix[~ESfemale[['methylation_state', 'position']].isin(EpiSC.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]
print(diff1)
diff1.to_csv('diff1.csv')

diff2 = EpiSC.ix[~EpiSC[['methylation_state', 'position']].isin(ESfemale.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]
print(diff2)
diff2.to_csv('diff2.csv')
```

PS there were no "intersecting" sets in your sample files, so i had to add a few rows form file1 to file 2 and vice versa in order to test it.

Comment: thank you so much for everything. Important that I now understand every aspect and see If I can re-write it and get same results. but this works - thank you so much! I really appreciate all your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

How about as following

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Input_Sample1.txt', names=['read_name', 'methylation_state', 'position'], usecols=['position', 'methylation_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Input_Sample2.txt', names=['read_name', 'methylation_state', 'position'], usecols=['position', 'methylation_state'], delimiter=r'\s+')
m1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left') # merge one that exist on df1
m2 = df2.merge(df1, how='left') # merge one that exist on df2
```